# How can I find websites that route through a specific router at my ISP?

Tags: networking, routing, isp

My internet connection has packet loss, but only for TCP SYN packets, and only to a handful of websites. Trying to convince my ISP's support hotline that there is an issue when the only examples I can give are a site called "hacker news" with an even more unusual domain (ycombinator) and my own email/web/etc. server hosted on a residential connection... phone support opens a ticket but the next day it gets closed with "no issue could be identified on the line". I tried to get them to write details in the ticket like "it concerns SYN packets", but twice now they've just closed the ticket and it's a huge pain when trying to access my email, grocery list, etc. (I host a lot of things for myself).

If I could show them a whole list of websites that are all having trouble, it would both sound more like a legitimate problem and also is much less likely to be a specific website's own problem.

<sub>I have already ruled out that it's the website's own problem, but the details for that are beyond the scope of this question (I'm not looking for help diagnosing the problem, I already know it's outside of my control).</sub>

In a traceroute I can see two routers (hop 4, ae0 and ae1), within the ISP's network, where the packet loss starts:

```
$ sudo mtr 45.80.169.218 --tcp -P 80  # the port does not matter
                                                             Packets  
 Host                                                      Loss%   Snt
 1. <my own router>                                         0.0%    59
 2. loopback1.0001.acln.02.dus.de.net.telefonica.de         0.0%    59
 3. ae14-0.0002.dbrx.02.dus.de.net.telefonica.de            0.0%    59
    ae14-0.0001.dbrx.02.dus.de.net.telefonica.de
 4. ae1-0.0003.prrx.02.dus.de.net.telefonica.de            51.7%    58
    ae0-0.0003.prrx.02.dus.de.net.telefonica.de
 5. ae2-100-grtdusix1.net.telefonicaglobalsolutions.com    47.4%    58
 6. 176.52.248.83                                          37.9%    58
 7. 94.144.107.49                                          50.0%    58
 8. ae-2.r21.frnkge13.de.bb.gin.ntt.net                    47.4%    58
 9. ae-7.r21.amstnl07.nl.bb.gin.ntt.net                    43.9%    58
10. ae-1.a01.amstnl09.nl.bb.gin.ntt.net                    52.6%    58
11. xe-1-5-0-3.a01.amstnl09.nl.ce.gin.ntt.net              49.1%    58
12. cr0.nikhef.nl.fusixnetworks.net                        53.4%    58
13. ae1-1197.core0.fi001.nl.freedomnet.nl                  54.4%    58
14. connected.by.freedom.nl                                49.1%    58
15. lucgommans.nl                                          59.6%    58
```

**How can I find more websites/networks that pass through this faulty router?**

I've tried looking in a BGP looking glass, to see if I can find some networks that would route via this system, but I'm not really well-versed in global routing enough to truly know what I'm looking at. Perhaps I'd need to look in the internal routing information of my ISP (igp rather than bgp, if I understood correctly)? In that case, the answer would be "you cannot do this" (short of just brute force guessing), right?

Comment: I think you'll struggle. Traceroute doesn't necessarily use the same route you'd get if you went to the same place via a browser. It *might*, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: You cannot reliably determine where packet loss is occurring from your end. Big routers often cannot be bothered to send _ICMP Time Exceeded_ packets every time the condition occurs. In this case, the numbers on later routers are more or less the same so it _could_ be the issue.

Comment: @DanielB I might indeed be wrong about where it is happening. However, if there is a method of finding other websites that are routed via a given router at my ISP, then I would be able to just go up or down the list of hops. This doesn't really change the answer to the question.

Comment: One difficulty is that routes are not symmetric. For example, if I in the UK try to reach a website hosted in France by OVH then my packets will jump on to the OVH network at the first possible point, but the return packets will typically leave OVH's network as soon as possible. Tools like `mtrr` can't really handle this very well and instead have to assume symmetry

Comment: You could always try a VPN. The route to the VPN provider may be better. You can also roll your own, maybe at Hetzner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What goes through this router" is entirely decided by the ISP's internal routing – you can't really see it from outside. (The global BGP routing table only tells you whole *networks* you might be going through, but what happens inside each network or 'autonomous system' is deliberately opaque.)

What you can do is randomly look for websites hosted on a) IP addresses within the same prefix as seen in BGP (e.g. 45.80.168.0/22 to follow the example in your traceroute), b) any other IP addresses advertised by the same AS (e.g. `bgpq3 AS206238`), and there's a high chance that they all will take the same path.

(Though this doesn't guarantee that the *reverse* path will also be the same.)

Note that at links #2-3 and #3-4, your ISP seems to be using multi-path routing – from router 2, the packets might be forwarded via router 3A or router 3B depending on IP addresses, TCP/UDP ports, &c. (For example, assuming everything else is the same, odd/even source ports might cause 3A/3B to be selected.) It could be that one of those links is bad while the other is fine.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid the answer would indeed be "cannot be done, this is internal to your ISP's configs". That one of the load balanced routes is bad is also my guess indeed. To address "*doesn't guarantee that the reverse path will also be the same*": the problem also happens in reverse (when connecting from Freedom to Telefonica) with 50% loss on SYNs, but the problem seems to start sooner (before making it to routers in DUS - Düsseldorf). If no further answers appear that have some clever trick to find this information efficiently, I will accept this answer. Thanks again :)